# Counting number of rows where two column requirements: String and Color

Tags: count

This would have been easier if the COUNTIF function works with cell colors. I have two columns, one is text and one is just a cell colour. It only counts if the text in the first column matches the required colour (yellow in this case).

```
  //yellow AIMS is "#ffd966"
  // red to be raised is "#ff0000"

function countCellBGColour(coc, rangeSpecification) {

  var color = "#ffd966";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var backGroundColors = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification).getBackgrounds();
  var cocsheet = sheet.getRange("Sheet1!E:E");

  var x = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < backGroundColors.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < backGroundColors[0].length; j++) {

      if(backGroundColors[i][j] == color && cocsheet == coc)
         { x++ }

    }
  }
  return x;
}
```